# Is it possible to get SQL-query by which a row was deleted?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm in `PostgreSQL 9.4` and would like to write a trigger which could store sql-queries affects a secific row. What do I mean?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION partner.daily_profit_logger() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT'
        INSERT INTO query_log (query) VALUES ( -- getting sql-query, performing the Insert operation
                                      )
        RETURN NEW;
END $$
language plpgsql;
```

Comment: so you want to write a trigger that saves the query that was executed?

Comment: I advice you to look at [this](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus) (To not reinvent the wheel)

Comment: I found an audit trigger on the postgresql wiki: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger

Answer (score 1):

Postgres has an [extensive logging facility setup](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-logging.html). You should probably look at `log_statement = mod` which will log all datamodifying queries (including but not restricted to `INSERT` and `DELETE`).

Cheers,